# How to pass the current user to a web control declaratively

Tags: asp.net, controls, asp.net-membership

I'm creating a control and need to pass it the current logon user as a parameter (declaratively)

I tried this but didn't work (I got "<%= User.Identity.Name %>" as value):

```
<cc1:MyControl id="myid" runat="server" User="<%= User.Identity.Name %>" />
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to pass it at all?. The user control can access the User.Identity.Name property directly.

Answer (score 1):

Inside that control, you will have access to this.Page.User, so that's one way.
Another is to use HttpContext.Current.User.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the codebehind:

```
myid.User = User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
User="<%= User.Identity.Name %>"
```

%= is for output

%# is for databinding.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it (I copied and pasted the second thing I tried). I did actaully tried first with "="

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the double quotes in the User attribute to single quotes.  I've seen that work in the past...